# jackson serialize by type with mixing?

Tags: java, jackson, jackson2

I have a something like this as a json and need to convert it to a Java User-Instance by Jackson.

```
"userid" : "1",
"myMixes" : [ {
     "data" : {
       "id" : 1,
       "ref": "my-Object-instance"
     },
     "type" : "object"
   }, {
     "data" : [ [ 0, 1], [ 1, 2 ] ],
     "type" : "list"
   }]
```

I have this in my class "User":

```
    // jackson should use this, if type="list"
    @JsonProperty("data")
    public List<List<Integer>> data_list = new ArrayList<>();

    // jackson should use this, if type="object"
    @JsonProperty("data")
    public Data data_object;

    @JsonProperty("id")
    public String id;

    // if type = "object", then jackson should convert json-data-property to Java-Data-Instance
// if type = "list",then jackson should convert json-data-property to List<List<Integer>> data
    @JsonProperty("type")
    public String type;
```

How can I tell jackson to generate a Data-Instance of the json-data-property, if value of json-type-property is called "object" and to generate a List-Instance, if value of json-type-property is called "list".

Answer (score 1):

I guess, I found the best solution:

```
@JsonCreator
    public MyMixes(Map<String,Object> props)
    {
        ...

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        if(this.type.equals("object")){

            this.data_object = mapper.convertValue(props.get("data"), Data.class);
        }
        else{
            this.data = mapper.convertValue(props.get("data"), new TypeReference<List<List<Integer>>>() { });
        }

    }
```

If someone has a shorter/faster way, then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own deserializer that checks the type property value of the received json. Something like:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = UserDeserializer.class)
public class UserData {
    ...
}



public class UserDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Item> { 

public UserDeserializer() { 
    this(null); 
} 

public UserDeserializer(Class<?> vc) { 
    super(vc); 
}

@Override
public UserData deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
  throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
    String type = node.get("type");
    if(type.equals("object")){
    // deserialize object
    }else if(type.equals("list")){
    // deserialize list
    }
    return new UserData(...);
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the difference of my solution and yours? Is yours faster?